# MongoEngine, loading model deletes existing documents

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, mongoengine

I'm confused about why loading a mongonengine model deletes that collection from my mongodb database.

I'm running mongoengine (0.10.6) in a Python2.7 application and have had to create a script to save data into the database.

My script to save data uses this code (a minimal example of what's going on, so it's only the relevant information):

```
#add_data.py
import mongoengine as mongo
from models import education_models

db_name = 'db_test'
db_url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
mongo.connect(db_name, host=db_url)

education_models.EducationProgram(title="Program 1").save()
```

Using that process, I can query the database later in the program and retrieve my data.

However, I have a separate process that does much the same:

```
#get_data.py
import mongoengine as mongo
from models import education_models

db_name = 'db_test'
db_url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
mongo.connect(db_name, host=db_url)

record = education_models.EducationProgram.objects(title="Program 1").first()
print record.title
```

This has an error to say the Nonetype has no title.

When I open the mongo shell, `mongo`, I can see the databases I've created but there's nothing inside. I can run at my terminal:

```
show dbs
use db_test
db_test.education_program.findOne({title:"Program 1"})
db_test.education_program.count()
```

If I run the above commands before the second process, it returns the expected documents and count. If I run it after the second process, all documents are gone. I even tried making a script that merely loaded the model for the saved documents and that deletes the documents.

Why does loading the model delete all instances of the data in my database?

Here is the (shortened) contents of education_models:

```
import mongoengine as mongo

class EducationProgram(mongo.Document): 
    program_title = mongo.StringField(required=True, unique = True) 
    program_code = mongo.StringField() 
    ...
```

Comment: *" ran mongod but found I was missing the path data/db ..."* Are you saying you did this **after** running the scripts indicated and that was the message received? If so then that is concerning and would indicate that you are not connecting to where you think you are connecting to. Indeed are your "minimal examples" the actual code you are running, or is this what you just stripped down from your actual code for purposes of this post, but have never actually run as is? An MCVE really needs the "V" as in you actually tried it yourself.

Comment: I'm really thinking that this is actually all about what is not being said. I'm thinking along the lines of MongoDB in a docker container maybe? Again work on that "V", as there needs to be a case that is possible to reproduce.

Comment: No, I've since run the scripts after the changes. The examples are minimal in the sense that dumping the entire script to StackOverflow would be useless. I thought all of this was pretty obvious. No docker env.

Comment: What's in `education_models`?

Comment: Thanks @guessimtoolate , shows what the model does.

Comment: What is was trying to establish was if your education model somehow overwrites/clears/drops the collection when it's initiated. Can't really tell from that snippet so, I'm out of ideas.